# Handling WPF Editable combobox when entered text is not a part of datsource

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox

I have a Combobox in WPF, I have set Is Editable="true" which allows me enter any text in the combobox. I would like to restrict users from entering text outside datasource.

**Xaml:**

```
<ComboBox Name="service" Margin="0,0,0,4" 
    IsEditable="True"
    Grid.Column="1" 
    Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="4" 
    SelectedValuePath="Id" 
    DisplayMemberPath="Service" 
    SelectedValue="{Binding Controller.Service1}" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding}" />
```

**C#:**

```
System.Data.DataView vw = tableAdapterServices.GetData().DefaultView;
service.ItemsSource = vw;
service.SelectedIndex = 0;
```

I do not want to allow users to enter text which is not present in the datasource, or handle it if the user enters any other text.

**Update:**

Thanks for the solution @Vishal, LostFocus event is handling the issue, but it gave rise to another issue. I have a button which is used to submit the combobox value along with other textbox values to the server. I am setting default value in the combobox in lostfocus event. But I need to prevent the button click event if some value other that datasource value is added in combobox.

Comment: You can change the enabled/disabled state of the button depending on SelectedIndex of combobox. I have updated my answer with relevent code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check for selectedIndex in Lostfocus event :

```
private void ComboBox_LostFocus(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(((ComboBox)sender).SelectedIndex == -1)
    {
        //Text entered by user is not a part your ItemsSource's Item
        SaveButton.IsEnabled = false; 
    }
    else
    {
        //Text entered by user is a part your ItemsSource's Item
        SaveButton.IsEnabled = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try handling the ComboBox's TextInput or PreviewTextInput events, doing the text search yourself, selecting the most appropriate item, and setting "e.Handled = true."
This works for a single character (i.e. if you enter the letter "j", it will select the first item that contains a "j" or "J"), but I'm sure there's a way to do this with your control. Just include a little more logic to achieve this.

```
private void MyComboBox_PreviewTextInput(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e) {
foreach (ComboBoxItem i in MyComboBox.Items) {
    if (i.Content.ToString().ToUpper().Contains(e.Text.ToUpper())) {
        MyComboBox.SelectedItem = i;
        break;
    }
}
e.Handled = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, from what I understand the behaviour of the combobox should disregard an inserted character if there is no item in the datasource that contains the resulted string.

I believe you are doing it in a MVVM style since you are using binding. What you can do is to bind the ComboBox text to a property and the PreviewTextInput event to a command and do the filtering there.

**XAML:**

```
<ComboBox Name="service" 
          Margin="0,0,0,4" 
          IsEditable="True"                      
          Grid.Column="1" 
          Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
          Grid.Row="4" 
          SelectedValuePath="Id" 
          DisplayMemberPath="Service" 
          SelectedValue="{Binding Controller.Service1}" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding}" 
          Text="{Binding Text, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
          >
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="PreviewTextInput">
                <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding TextInputCommand}"  PassEventArgsToCommand="True" />
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</Combobox>
```

**C#** ViewModel:

```
    public RelayCommand<object> TextInputCommand { get; set; }

    public bool CanExecuteTextInputCommand(object param)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public void ExecuteTextInputCommand(object param)
    {
        TextCompositionEventArgs e = param as TextCompositionEventArgs;
        string currentText = this.Text;
        string entireText = string.Format("{0}{1}", currentText, e.Text);

        var item = this.Items.Where(d => d.StartsWith(entireText)).FirstOrDefault();
        if (item == null)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
            this.Text = currentText;
        }
    }
```

Where `Items` is the ObservableCollection containing the items (in this case it's a list of strings) and `Text` is the property binded to the Combobox text.

**EDIT:** Ok so what you need to do to make it work is to go to your project, right click on References, choose Manage NuGet Packages, search and install `MVVM Light`. Two dlls that start with `GalaSoft` will be added to your references. After this, in your xaml code add these namespaces:

```
xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
xmlns:cmd="clr-namespace:GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Command;assembly=GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Extras.WPF4"
```

What this allows you to do is to bind an event to a ICommand object.

Comment: I am new to WPF. Yes, I am using MVVM style. I am getting error `The attachable property 'Triggers' was not found in type 'Interaction'.` when i use the you xaml.